# a html element is routing a link to the development server

Tags: javascript, html, dom, routes, anchor

I am trying to dynamically create a HTML element (**Anchor Tag**) from
a form.

All the logic is working but when I click on the anchor text, I am
routed to the development server(LIVE SERVER) to
http://127.0.0.1:5500/google.com.

The error message in the console shows "**Cannot GET /google.com**".

What is the best way to solve this problem?

This is the html element

```
<li >
 <span class="trash"></span>
 <a href="google.com" rel='external' target='_blank'>Google</a>
</li>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% what you want to acheive here. Could you please add more details? Maybe you just need to add the full path `https://www.google.com/` instead of `google.com` for the `href` attribute.

Comment: I received an answer, thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the browser interpreting the `href` as a relative link.

If the link is to an external site, make sure to use a fully qualified name such as `https://www.google.com`

Comment: so what do you recommend to do ?
validation in the form ? adding alway http::// because http changes to https ?

Comment: Ok, not sure I understood.  Do users enter a URL and you want to provide a link to click it?  If so, I would add validation to ensure the value begins with ‘http://‘ or ‘https://‘

Comment: exactly the user insert title (string) ->( innerHTML) and url (string)-> ( href) 
- if i always add http:// should automatically route to https:// ?

Comment: No, the not all websites reroute http to https.  This is a best practice but some older sites may not have this behavior.

Comment: thnks very much